# Control panel dropdown submenus not expanding?

Tags: control-panel, javascript

I can't figure out why my dropdown submenu's aren't expanding? No JS errors either?

I am using Zoo Flexible admin but when I hide the custom menu or reset to default the issue still persists? Any ideas?

EE 2.5.3
Zoo Flexible Admin 1.62

Third Party folders are outside of `system` & `themes` folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with Nico (Zoo) & Manuel (DevDemon) to isolate the issue. The problem was with [Editor](http://www.devdemon.com/editor/) and the `cp_css` extension hook it was using which cause a PHP error in the CSS. Manuel patched and should be in the next release.

Answer (score 4):

This is usually caused by a JavaScript error or error loading an asset file.

You should turn on your browser's developer tools and look for any 404s in addition to the JavaScript errors you looked for to begin debugging this type of problem.

Comment: Checked all that. No 404's or JS errors. Tried Chrome, Firefox & Safari. However I did just notice this when logging into Safari (not my default browser): `Your ExpressionEngine installation’s version (..) is not consistent with the reported version (2.5.3)`

Comment: The issue is with Zoo Flexible Admin. I contacted them. I will post an update once I hear